# How to load local file to WINSCP with password?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, putty, winscp, pscp

I used codes in below link with my batch script. But it is asking for password. When I provided pw with password it is not working. First Time it is aking for yes or no when I try in command prompt. In second try it is not asking like that. So I need batch script which need to load local file to WINSCP with password. Also need to answer y.

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html

Sample code I used in batch script:

```
pscp c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo
pw Exam454656.
```

Comment: `pscp -pw Exam454656 c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo` maybe?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes it is working. Thanks. But I'm not able to find tick mark to accept your answer. Only find upvote.

Comment: Because it was just a comment. Not sure if I can really make it a worthy answer, but let me post one.

Comment: You cannot load anything to WinSCP. It's SCP/SFTP server that you are (up)loading to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pscp` has some specific parameters. `-pw` is the one you are looking for.

```
pscp -pw Exam454656 c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo
```